# Preprocessing the image for findContours

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I'm trying to detect contours of the flag on the background with

```
canny = cv2.Canny(np.asarray(out_gray), 50, 200)
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(canny.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(image=out, contours=contours, contourIdx=-1, color=(255, 0, 0), thickness=20)
plt.imshow(out)
plt.show()
```

But as I get not desirable result.

[image]

What is the best approach to preprocesing image to find contours?

Answer (score 0):

If you resize the image before process you get more contours.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('flag.png')
img = cv2.resize(img, (1200, 700)) # <---- resize here!
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

canny = cv2.Canny(np.asarray(gray), 0, 200)

_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(canny.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)


cv2.drawContours(image=img, contours=contours, contourIdx=-1, color=(255, 255, 0), thickness=5)

cv2.imshow('asd', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Output:

[image]

Canny image with resize:

[image]

Canny image without resize:

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you! How does the size influence to the quality of the canny? But If I have a lot of the same images, what is the best size to resize?

Comment: I think it might be because of the interpolation done in the resize. It uses Bilinear interpolation at default. You can check out different interpolations here: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga5bb5a1fea74ea38e1a5445ca803ff121.
I'm not sure what the best size would be but I just resized the image to fit my screen while still maintaining the image ratio.