# How can I draw/contour the edges of shapes in an image without false positives?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

I'm trying to make a script in which I can draw the contour of every shape in an image, which works in some cases but fails when the shape has some degradations in the color. It was meant to draw the contour of the shape (a rectangle in this case) but could not draw the whole rectangle and also added some point inside which is a false positive. Is there a way I can add less sensitivity to the script or another tool that could help me to achieve this?

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import imutils
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np


print("OpenCV Version: {}".format(cv2.__version__))
image = cv2.imread("input.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 225, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
if imutils.is_cv2() or imutils.is_cv4():
    (cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
elif imutils.is_cv3():
    (_, cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

cv2.drawContours(image, cnts, -1, (50, 50, 50),24)

RGBimage = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
PILimage = Image.fromarray(RGBimage)
PILimage.save('output.png', dpi=(300,300))
```

Comment: can you post the original image too I would like totry your code. I am trying to learn pillow

Comment: dont know how findcontours works, can you just trasform your image in same way such that it will have only two colors ? tha docs says Contours can be explained simply as a curve joining all the continuous points (along the boundary), having same color or intensity. The contours are a useful tool for shape analysis and object detection and recognition.

    For better accuracy, use binary images. So before finding contours, apply threshold or canny edge detection.

Comment: change your threshold

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html

Comment: @lorelayb Hi using your code and https://ibb.co/19Hh0kb as input I get https://ibb.co/zZkS5TX as output so your code seems to work. using the input that you uploaded returns the input image as output not sure if it is somehow related to countur finding whites over black as countours

Comment: @lorelayb sorry the above post gives output using thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 255, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]  so if you put in trshhold 225 -> 255 you gest a rectangle

Comment: @lorelayb ibb.co/q7vf0jV is your original output with thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 255, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1] while ibb.co/ypLHCcq is your original output with thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 250, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1] in this case len(cnts) : 25 meaning you have 25 countours. Do you know how to get an Image out from every single counturs ? to have a look at them

Comment: found for all of them:img_contours = np.zeros(image.shape)

cv2.drawContours(img_contours, cnts, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
print('img_contours : ', img_contours.shape)
img_cnt_rgb = Image.fromarray((img_contours).astype(np.uint8))
print(img_cnt_rgb, '    ',img_cnt_rgb.size,'   ', img_cnt_rgb.mode)
    
img_cnt_rgb.show()

Comment: https://ibb.co/hBxWksr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change threshold values with:

thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 250, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]

Comment: Thank you! found that changing the threshold was actually the key, not sure yet what is the best way to calculate the threshold but will try making different tests so I can have a better idea of how to pick the values to work across different scenarios, but hopefully something around 250,255 will keep working across different scenarios.

Comment: dont know either guess depends on the range of gray you have that depends on the range of colors you have. Have a look at this: is interesting in terms of optimizing findcounturs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58523157/preprocessing-the-image-for-findcontours

Comment: https://medium.com/@anupriyam/basic-image-thresholding-in-opencv-5af9020f2472